# How to use POP3 over SSL in C

Tags: c, ssl, pop3

I would like to know and understand the steps involved in fetching mail from pop3 server
using plain c language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Connect to the server's port (usually 995) using [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html)
2. Verify the certificate
3. Send regular pop3 commands over the SSL socket you just opened. (LIST, RETR and so on)
4. Retrieve the responses
5. Close the socket

Or use a library that does all of the above for you

Comment: doesn't ssl imply asyncronous certificate ?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the thousands of libraries that already exist such as [libspopc](http://brouits.free.fr/libspopc/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a library such as [tinymail](http://tinymail.org/trac/tinymail/wiki), which uses the OpenSSL library.