# Reading message from socket hangs

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ssl, pop3

I'm trying to connect to a pop3 mail server using TCP, but when I try to `read()` the message right after `connect()` the console just hangs.

```
int sd;
struct sockaddr_in server;

if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror ("Error: socket()\n");
    return errno;
}

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ADDR);
server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Error: connect()\n");
    return errno;
}

char message[100];
read(sd, message, 100); // <== here it hangs
printf ("message: %s\n", message);

close (sd);
```

Where `ADDR` is the ip and `PORT` is the port of the server I'm trying to connect (in my case 188.125.69.47 and 995).
From what I've read in the RFC, after `connect()` I should receive a following message:

```
+OK hello from ....
```

Comment: You're connecting to **POP3s**, which is POP3 over SSL. You would need to initiate SSL connection first. Compare `nc -v 188.125.69.47 995` (nothing there) with `openssl s_client -connect 188.125.69.47:995` (*+OK hello...*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your read doesn't give you anything, because server is not sending any data. You're right that in POP3 server should send you a hello message first, but as you're connecting to [POP3 over port 995](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol#STARTTLS), the SSL session needs to be established first. This however requires an initial [handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake) from the client.

You'll need a library to establish SSL connection and then talk in POP3, for example [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html).

Answers in this question might be also helpful: 
[How to use POP3 over SSL in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137741/how-to-use-pop3-over-ssl-in-c).

Comment: Thanks, I've found [this](http://savetheions.com/2010/01/16/quickly-using-openssl-in-c/) example, on how to use ssl and now works.